# Как удалить из HashMap RxJava2 правильно?

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

У меня есть `Map<CallServiceCode, List<CallServicePart>>` и есть текущее значение ключа `CallServiceCode mCurrentCallServiceCall`

Мне нужно получить `value` по этому `mCurrentCallServiceCall` ключу и проверить есть `size == 1` , то удалить из `Map`, `key` и соответственно `value` , а если `size > 1` , то удалить из `value` первый элемент.

Вот как я это сделал

```
public void checkForDelete()
{
    List<CallServicePart> currentList = mUnansweredQuestionMap.get(mCurrentCallServiceCall);

    Observable.fromIterable(currentList) //
              .count()//
              .subscribe(iCount ->
              {
                  if (iCount == 1)
                  {
                      mUnansweredQuestionMap.remove(mCurrentCallServiceCall);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      List<CallServicePart> list = Observable.fromIterable(currentList)//
                                                             .toList()//
                                                             .blockingGet();
                      list.remove(0);
                  }
              });
}
```

Но мне вообще не нравиться как это выглядит и я уверен, что можно написать это нормально.

Подскажите, что сделал не так

Comment: А зачем здесь Rx?

Comment: @post_zeew я просто начал пробовать применение Rx и для понимания пробую применить его везде где есть работа со списками, мапами и т.д.

Comment: Не нужно пихать Rx везде. У каждой технологии есть область применения.

Comment: Rx тут не нужен от слова совсем. Вы же не используете перебор списка в цикле со счетчиком для получения количества элементов в списке? Так что просто воспользуйтесь стандартными возможностями языка в данной ситуации

Comment: @temq Да согласен, что это не сложно делается с помощью стандартных методов, просто сейчас хочу попрактиковать рх и поэтому вот так)) Все таки мне интересно как это сделать с рх, хотя бы просто для того, чтоб увидеть и понять как, потому что как я описал в вопросе пока что не ясно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня вопрос - оно работает? К сожалению не могу воспроизвести у себя данный код, чтобы проверить свои доводы, но давайте разберемся, что вы делаете.

Сначала из мепа по ключу достаете список. тут всё ОК.

Затем, вы создаете `ObservableSource` из списка. Подсчитывается количество элементов в этом `ObservableSource` (не в списке, а именно в самом объекте).
Затем подписываетесь на него, если количество = 1 то удаляете из мапы по ключу.
Иначе (тут начинается что-то непонятное) Вы опять создаете `ObservableSource` из списка `currentList`, который разбивает список на отдельные элементы. Потом тут же их собираете в список (зачем???) и в конце всё это с `blockingGet()`. Зачем данный оператор, если вы и так работаете в одном потоке. RxJava, если вы ей не укажете `subscribeOn/observeOn`, работает синхронно, т.е. выполняется последовательно в текущем потоке.
И затем из списка (который не является изначальным, а новым, т.к. `toList()` вам собирает новый объект) удаляется ссылка на нулевой элемент, а в старом списке ссылка на него как была так и есть, т.е. в мапе элемент останется.

Вопрос: зачем тут вообще RxJava? Реактив ради реактива это такое себе решение.
Как бы сделал я? Вообще не использовал бы в данной ситуации Rx. Код должен быть максимально простым, а применяемые инструменты оправданными.

```
public void checkForDelete() { //название метода тоже не очень. слово check (проверка) хотя тут кроме проверки и само удаление происходит.
        List<CallServicePart> currentList = mUnansweredQuestionMap.get(mCurrentCallServiceCall);
        if(currentList == null || currentList.isEmpty()) // return error

        if(currentList.size() == 1) {
                 mUnansweredQuestionMap.remove(mCurrentCallServiceCall);
        } else {
                 currentList.remove(0)
        }
}
```

Как по мне код куда более минималистичен и читабелен.

P.S. могу ошибаться в своих доводах, в комментариях прошу указать на ошибки, ответ будет удален после конструктивной критики :)

Comment: Да согласен, что это не сложно делается с помощью стандартных методов, просто сейчас хочу попрактиковать рх и поэтому вот так)) Все таки мне интересно как это сделать с рх, хотя бы просто для того, чтоб увидеть и понять как, потому что как я описал в вопросе пока что не ясно

Comment: Rx работает с иммутабельными (неизменяемыми) данными. т.е. если у вас стоит задача удалить из списка элемент, вы не можете менять сам список. вы можете только сформировать новый с пощью разных операторов, к примеру  filter() map() flatMap()  и затем в subscribe() переприсвоить старому списку новый. Если вы хотите познать Rx. В первую очередь необходимо понять зачем его придумали, какие проблемы он решает и какие основные принципы в себе несет